# How to share a text and link in instagram using xamarin ios?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, instagram

I want to share a text and link to Instagram from my app.I tried this link to implement this:-https://xamarinhelp.com/share-dialog-xamarin-forms/. But in the sharing option instagram doesn't showing.

Please help me..

```
  public class Share : IShare
   {     
       string _path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
       string _fileName = "image.png";
        // MUST BE CALLED FROM THE UI THREAD
   public async Task Show(string title, string message, string filePath)
    {
var items = new NSObject[] { NSObject.FromObject(title), NSUrl.FromFilename(Path.Combine(_path , _fileName )) };
var activityController = new UIActivityViewController(items, null);
var vc = GetVisibleViewController();

NSString[] excludedActivityTypes = null;

if (excludedActivityTypes != null && excludedActivityTypes.Length > 0)
    activityController.ExcludedActivityTypes = excludedActivityTypes;

if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(8, 0))
{
    if (activityController.PopoverPresentationController != null)
    {
        activityController.PopoverPresentationController.SourceView = vc.View;
    }
}
await vc.PresentViewControllerAsync(activityController, true);      
}

UIViewController GetVisibleViewController()
{
    var rootController = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController;

if (rootController.PresentedViewController == null)
    return rootController;

if (rootController.PresentedViewController is UINavigationController)
{
    return ((UINavigationController)rootController.PresentedViewController).TopViewController;
}

if (rootController.PresentedViewController is UITabBarController)
{
        return ((UITabBarController)rootController.PresentedViewController).SelectedViewController;
}

return rootController.PresentedViewController;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Please notice `filePath` is the image's name which is embedded in your iOS project and make sure its build action is `BundleResource`.

Then when you click the share button to open the `UIActivityViewController` window. Find the Instagram App via clicking the More button:

[image]

Turn on the switch of Instagram. You could also adjust the order of it. At last, you can successfully share items to Instagram.

Comment: :- The Instagram app is not displaying in the more options, That is my issue.And all the other apps are working fine.

Comment: Have you tried the ShareDialog  repo of the blog you posted above? It works fine on my side.

Comment: I am updated my code , now the instagram is displaying in the more options, but actually I want to share a data and url with instagram , Is it possible?

Comment: @John What kind of data? It depends on Instagram. If it accepts the data it will be shown on the share window otherwise it won't.

Comment: Sorry, I mean a text and url

Comment: @John I think it should contain a title string. If you don't want that you can pass an empty string like "". But I haven't tried you can pass two items as you want for testing.

Comment: Is that possible to share an image with caption in iOS?

Comment: @John It depends on Instagram. Once you have shared messages to Instagram, the next process is handled by Instagram. But I think it doesn't support that. You'd better attach an image with text on itself.